# How to get classname in objective c Like 'NSString'

Tags: objective-c, class

I want to get the class name of an object as what we are using.
That means now if I write this code

```
 NSString *s = [NSString string];
 NSLog(@"%@",[s class]);
```

The output is `__NSCFConstantString`

How can I get it as `NSString` itself ?

Note : `NSString` is just an example

I know  `__NSCFConstantString` is correct. But my intention is to get like  `NSString`. Is there any way to acheive this?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to know the name of the class?

Comment: What you have *is* the name of the class. Not being what you expected doesn't mean it's wrong. The question is what you want to use the name for?

Comment: @Wain I didn't mean __NSCFConstantString is wrong. I know its correct. But I need it as NSString

Comment: How do you define `NSString` as correct?

Comment: *Just need it like NSString* This is a hint that your architecture is broken.

Comment: @Wain need the public abstract superclass of that class cluster

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give these a try, they'll output `NSString`. Keep in mind, the second set requires importing the Objective-C runtime header.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSString *string = @"I'm a string.";


NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([string classForCoder]));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([string classForKeyedArchiver]));

NSLog(@"%s",class_getName([string classForCoder]));
NSLog(@"%s",class_getName([string classForKeyedArchiver]));
```

Now, this won't work in all cases. For example, trying to get the class of `NSConstantString`, in this manner will output `NSString`. If you require checking the class name as a string in this way, you probably should reconsider your approach to solving the problem.

Comment: This What I need. You understand my question and answered.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about these methods. And they even distinguish  between NSString and NSMutableString. (But where is the difference between classForCoder/classForKeyedArchiver or classForArchiver ? Can the result be different?

Answer (score 3):

`NSString` is a so-called "class cluster". That means that the init methods will return
an instance of *some* subclass (such as `__NSCFConstantString` or `__NSCFString`).
You will never get an instance with the class equal to `NSString`.

If your intention is to *check* whether an object is a `NSString` or not then
use `isKindOfClass`:

```
if ([s isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // this is a string …
}
```

Other examples of class clusters are `NSNumber`, `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`
and their mutable variants.

Comment: How can I get the public abstract super class of these class

Comment: @Johnykutty: You could traverse the `superclass` chain until you find something that you know about. In this case that would be `__NSCFConstantString -> __NSCFString -> NSMutableString -> NSString -> NSObject`. But this would really be a hack. - Perhaps you can explain better why you need that information, there might be a better solution. - Is `isKindOfClass` not sufficient?

Comment: @Johnykutty: For strings, there are two public abstract super classes: `NSString` and `NSMutableString`. But as you can see from my previous comment, even a *constant string*  inherits from `NSMutableString`. - Therefore it is impossible to determine *the* public abstract super class.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([s class]));
```

Comment: output is __NSCFConstantString need as NSString