# Unit-test testing for class equality

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, unit-testing, xctest

I'm adding some unit tests to a project and want to have a test that checks that the array returned from a method is immutable so I created the following unit test:

```
- (void)testReturnedObjectIsOfTypeImmutableArray
{
    XCTAssertEqualObjects([NSArray class],
                          [[NSArray reverseArray:self.array] class],
                          @"NSArray should be returned");
}
```

However this fails because the object being returned is of class "__NSArrayI" instead of "NSArray".

I can't work out how to adapt the above to have "_*NSArrayI" be acceptable where as receiving "*_NSArrayM" or "NSMutableArray" should be unacceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the answer to 
[How to get classname in objective c Like 'NSString'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526637/how-to-get-classname-in-objective-c-like-nsstring), you could use `classForCoder` instead of `class`. Example:

```
NSArray *a = @[@"foo"];
NSMutableArray *b = [a mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"a class: %@", [a class]); // -> __NSArrayI
NSLog(@"b class: %@", [b class]); // -> __NSArrayM
NSLog(@"a classForCoder: %@", [a classForCoder]); // -> NSArray
NSLog(@"b classForCoder: %@", [b classForCoder]); // -> NSMutableArray
```

So this test should give the expected results:

```
- (void)testReturnedObjectIsOfTypeImmutableArray
{
    XCTAssertEqualObjects([NSArray class],
                          [[NSArray reverseArray:self.array] classForCoder],
                          @"NSArray should be returned");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that solutions works really well for what I need

Answer (score 2):

Testing for class equality is a problem with class clusters.

Use `isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]` to check whether the object is a subclass of `NSArray` and then check if it responds to selector `@selector(addObject:)` to see if it's mutable.

```
BOOL isArray = [self.array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]];
BOOL isMutable = [self.array respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:)];
XCTAssertTrue(isArray && !isMutable, @"...");
```

Comment: (+1) This is a more straightforward solution than mine. (An unrelated but interesting point might be that such a check does not work with NS(Mutable)String. That's why I came up with a different method.)

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, I'm going to go with Martin R's solution just because it would work with other classes and so set a standard for these types of tests within the project

Answer (score 0):

`_NSArrayI` **is** an `NSArray`, so if your `reverseArray` is returning a NSArray, it should work.